# Connecting to Pi over the internet - Already tried a lot of things

Tags: raspbian, ssh, remote, ethernet-port

I read some tutorials here on connecting to my Pi via SSH. I have successfully done this over my own network. I am trying to do it from the internet (I use my phone's hotspot to attempt from outside my network), but I have had no success.

I have verizon fios, and although I do not have an official static IP address, it rarely changes (i've never seen it change in over a year) so I was just going to connect using my IP address versus setting up my own free DNS.

I am thinking I may just be misunderstanding port forwarding; here's what I did:

I made a new rule for my static raspberry pi address, saying to listen to any port, and forward to port 22 on the pi.

I use putty to attempt to connect by typing in my IP address and using port 22.

Some direction on this would be appreciated... I've been at it for hours.

Comment: I forgot to mention, when I go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/

it says my port 22 is closed.

Comment: (Sorry, I cannot 'comment' so I'll have to 'answer'). Could you please elaborate a little more on where you configured that port forwarding of yours? It's got to be in the WAN-connecting router of course. If you do not trust the port forwarding of this device maybe setup a simple server (ssh, web or ftp) on a laptop or desktop machine to verify. Besides the forwarding of the ssh relevant port 22 you will need no further settings concerning listening or whatever. If you suspect the Pi's sshd to fail you should be looking in that matter too. Obviously you should be checking to connect to it on y

Comment: Ok, so everything does work fine when I connect inside the network. Ill try my best to elaborate here. I will start by saying that the problem probably is with me; I am a new pi owner, and I have never remotely connected to anything before... So thanks in advance!

ssh status is running...

From uname -a: raspberrypi 3.12.22+ #691 PREEMPT Wed Jun 18 18:29:58 BST 2014 armv6l GNU/Linux

Sorry, the journalctl came back as command not found; like I said, I am new to the pi and linux. 

My pi has a static IP that I assigned to it. Again, it works fine on the LAN.

Comment: My port forwarding on my router is set up as TCP - any --> port 22. This is a rule for my raspberrypi specifically... 

Maybe I am missing a step there. The verizon router made this really easy by having SSH auto loaded.

Comment: I can say that when I go to http://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/
and test port 22, it always tells me closed. That seems an indication of the problem.

Comment: Sorry, just to clear things up - do you have a connection from your pi to the internet? What does `ping verizon.com` tell you run on the pi?

Comment: Hmm... Good point. When I was working in the pi directly, I had it connected to the internet... but I didnt set it up to auto connect (didnt know I had to). 

I cant ping anything right now, it tells me network unavailable... Ill go look up how to fix that.

Comment: Yeah I am not sure how to fix that... or if its abnormal. If I ping something in my network, it works, if I ping a website, it says Network unavailable.

the pi is connected vis ethernet to the internet.

When I loaded it earlier into the GUI, I could surf the web.

Comment: seconding "set PermitRootLogin no", port 22 on internet facing devices gets brute force attacks regularly.

Comment: Sure. Please try the things suggested by Morgan Courbet and provide logs as they might be helpful.

Comment: the basic problem is port forwarding... you want specific port to specific port..... WAN IP:22 to internal IP:22 or WAN IP:2022 to internal IP:22.

Comment: @JonathanAdams Mhh... didn't see your latest comment. What do the following commands return? `ifconfig -a`, `host google.com`, `traceroute google.com`

Comment: @Morgan, Both host google and traceroute google tell me Network is unreachable. 

my ifconfig:

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b8:27:eb:b4:3b:12
          inet addr:192.168.1.27  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:79934 errors:0 dropped:200 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:3385 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0

Comment: carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:5533640 (5.2 MiB)  TX bytes:498957 (487.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:1224 (1.1 KiB)  TX bytes:1224 (1.1 KiB)

Comment: @JonathanAdams I don't see anything wrong with this `ifconfig`. But since `host google.com` returns an error, it is likely a network configuration problem rather than a SSH configuration problem. It means your RPi cannot resolve name. However, it does not mean it cannot reach the Internet. You are able to ping other machines on your local network from your RPi, right? What about `ping 8.8.8.8` (Google's public DNS)? What about `cat /etc/resolv.conf`? Which Linux distro do you use? Did you just installed it?

Answer (score 3):

Obviously, the problem seems to be either the port forwarding configuration, or the ability for the SSH server/RPi to handle external connections.

### Port forwarding configuration

Maybe you should try with a specific external port. Let's say 10022 (external port) forward to your RPi IP address, port 22. Then from an external IP address, try `telnet <your IP address> 10022`. If you have a message similar to this:

```
$ telnet <your IP address> 10022
Trying <your IP address>...
Connected to <your IP address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Debian-7
```

...then, the port forwarding works well. Otherwise, you should try another server with another server, just to make sure your SSH server does not reject external connections.

#### `iperf`

I like to use `iperf` to make sure my device is reachable from my external network. This software allows you to test the bandwidth performances and, maybe it is not the fastest way, but it is lightweight and easy to use :-)

Install it from your RPi (`sudo apt-get install iperf`), then run `iperf -s`. The default listening port is 5001. So you will have to define another port forwarding (external port 5001 -> `<RPi IP address>`, port 5001). From an external IP address, run `telnet <your IP address> 5001`.

```
$ telnet <your IP address> 5001
Trying <your IP address>...
Connected to <your IP address>.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you see a similar message, then the port forwarding configuration works well. Otherwise, you should tweak your router...

### SSH server configuration

If none solution of the above worked, the problem is probably in the SSH server or RPi configuration.

#### `netstat`

We will make sure the SSH server listens for every hosts. Run `sudo netstat -anp | grep ssh`. You see the `0.0.0.0` part of the following line? It says "I [the SSH server] will listen the port 22 **but only** for the hosts matching `0.0.0.0`" (`0.0.0.0` means "every hosts"). If you don't see it, the problem is SSH server configuration (see next section):

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      21985/sshd
```

#### `/etc/ssh/ssh_config`

Please copy/paste the result of `cat /etc/ssh/ssh_config` in the comment section.

#### `/etc/hosts.deny` & `/etc/hosts.allow`

You can also have a look in the following files `/etc/hosts.deny` & `/etc/hosts.allow`. Please copy/paste the result of `cat /etc/hosts.deny` & `cat /etc/hosts.allow` in the comment section.

Comment: Host *
#ForwardAgent no
#ForwardX11 no
#ForwardX11Trusted yes
#RhostsRSAAuthentication no
#RSAAuthentication yes
#PasswordAuthentication yes
#HostbasedAuthentication no
#GSSAPIAuthentication no
#GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
#GSSAPIKeyExchange no
#GSSAPITrustDNS no
#BatchMode no
#CheckHostIP yes
#AddressFamily any
#ConnectTimeout 0
#StrictHostKeyChecking ask
#IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
#IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
#IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_dsa

Comment: #Port 22
#Protocol 2,1
#Cipher 3des
#Ciphers aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc
#MACs hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160
#EscapeChar ~
#Tunnel no
#TunnelDevice any:any
#PermitLocalCommand no
#VisualHostKey no
#ProxyCommand ssh -q -W %h:%p gateway.example.com
SendEnv LANG LC_*
HashKnownHosts yes
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no

Comment: I will start trying all the other things you said. Thank you very much for the explanations

Comment: @JonathanAdams Well, my `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file is very similar. What about the `~/.ssh/config` file?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely the problem is your ISP, check if your ISP blocks port 22 for security reasons (mine does).
Change the port to, for example 2222, portforward port 2222 on your router and try again.

```
ssh pi@yourpublicIPgoeshere -p 2222
```

**do note:** your ISP might also have a router installed in your home, in that case you need to forward port 2222 (or any port you want to forward) to the personal router's IP.

Again, this is also the case for me, I need to use a web portal my ISP provides to portforward on it.

**addition:**

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

change the port number

```
service ssh restart
```

then check if the port is open/usable

*As a sidequestion: did you have a router provided by your ISP?*

Comment: Now what I have been trying is other ports for the router to listen to (2233), but I am still trying to forward to port 22 on the pi. Would the ISP be blocking that?

Comment: To avoid confusion I would also let the pi listen to the new ssh port, but isps cant block your own router ports

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to thank you all for your help. The issue ended up being my gateway IP being 0.0.0.0. Once I changed it back, everything worked fine. I have no idea how that got messed up, because I did connect to the internet when I first got it.

Anyways, thanks again!